# Elegant way to push back std::array to std::vector N times

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

the following codes pushed back an std::array to a std::vector N times. Is there a more elegant and shorter way of doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

int main () {
  int N=10;
  std::vector< std::array<std::complex<double>,3> > v;
  v.reserve(N);
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    std::array<std::complex<double>,3> el { {0.0,3.0,0.0} };
    v.push_back(el);
  }
}
```

Comment: is it your array is fixed always ?

Comment: In your simple case, if this is the case at all, there is no need for pushing, just initialize it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/074dc1039efb7613

Comment: @kiranBiradar yes

Comment: @user1810087 In this simple example you are right. But in my code the vector is a member of a class. And when I create an object I have to specify the size of the vector. That's why I use v.reserve()

Comment: @JanSE you should probably mention this in your question. As it is now, it is confusing why the better answer for your current example is not the accepted one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add same value multiple times to std::vector (repeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998444/add-same-value-multiple-times-to-stdvector-repeat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) (#3 in the overload set) member function:

```
int N=10;
std::vector< std::array<std::complex<double>,3> > v;
v.reserve(N);

v.insert(v.end(), N,  { {0.0,3.0,0.0} });
```

Note that @MarekR's answer is preferable for initializing the vector, as it circumvents the call to `reserve`, and setting up an object during initialization is usually better than subsequent member function calls. The above call to `std::vector::insert` instead is suitable for adding additional elements later on.

Comment: While Marek's answer might be preferable on construction, this one is perfect for adding *additional* elements at some later point of time!

Answer (score 9):

Yes but you have to use parentheses when constructing vector

```
std::vector< std::array<std::complex<double>,3> > v(n, {0.0,3.0,0.0});
```

If braces are used than initialization list is preferred and in this case you could have unexpected errors.

Comment: I consider uniform initialisation a pure failure, so in consequence recommend *always* using parentheses anyway - even in case of initialiser list (`std::vector<int> v({1, 2, 3});`) for consistency...